# Display Alert message while having more than one zeros

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I've two UITextfields - `textfield1` and `textfield2`.

I'm just doing multiplication of the two textfields. `textfield2` has a fixed value and in `textfield1` user can set value by them self.

Now, I'm facing one problem. If the user sets value 0 then I'm displaying an alert message.

```
if ([textfield1.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APP_NAME message:@"You can not set Zero." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

But, if the user sets more than one zero or decimal zero (0.0 or 0.00) then I'm not able to display the alert message.

Comment: what if a user sets 0.0000003 ?

Comment: Simple rule. If you are going to make arithmetic operations use number types not strings.

Answer (score 5):

Don't work with strings. Convert to numbers:

```
double value1 = [textfield1.text doubleValue];
if (value1 == 0.0) {
    // show alert
}
```

**Update**: Actually, using `doubleValue` is not a good idea since you want to support users from around the world. Some users might enter values as `0.5` while another might use `0,5`, etc. It's better to use an `NSNumberFormatter` to convert the entered text to a number.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:textfield1.text];
double value1 = [number doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float value1 = [textfield1 text] floatValue];
int value2 = [textfield1 text] intValue];
if (value1 == 0.0 || value2 == 0) {
    // show alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add < UITextFieldDelegate > to your xxclass.h

and in xxclass.m implement delegate

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if([textField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [string isEqualToString:@"0"]){
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:APP_NAME message:@"You can not set Zero." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil]; [alert show];
    return NO; 
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. This prevents the user from typing in a value such as `0.5`.

Comment: YES, The premise is not allowed input float.

Comment: But that's not what the poster wants. Float is allowed, just not various forms of zero.